# How does group by statement in SQL affect the results ?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

Does including an extra column in group by change the number of rows in the results ?

I was doing a select query on a table A(col1,col2....col9) and I first included

```
select col1,col2,col3 
from A where col1 = (condition) 
group by col1, col2, col3
```

which yielded me certain number of results.

now I changed the query to this

```
`select col1,col2,col3, col8,col9 
from A where col1=(condition) 
group by col1,col2,col3, col8,col9'
```

and I got a different number of rows in the results. What could be the possible explanation ?

Comment: You are adding columns to the select list and the group by, if you have distinct values in those columns then you could get different  results.

Comment: You could be bringing back duplicate records or if one of these fields is a unique ID adding that to the group by will bring each one back. If you showed us the actual query we could have a better idea...

Comment: the query is on confidential data and hence I cant post here. But I see your point.
And the extra group by columns aren't unique. So I was wondering how the row change would have happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the combination of col1, col2 and col3 is not unique, you can have more than one row with the same combination of those three.

If that happens, *and* those duplicates have different values for col8 and/or col9, then grouping by those extra columns will result in more rows.

Note that you can use `select distinct` to get the same results. `group by` is especially used if you want to aggregate over other columns, for instance, calculate a sum or a count, like so:

```
select 
  col1, col2, col3, 
  sum(col8) as total8 
from A 
group by col1, col2, col3
```

The query above will give you each unique combination of col1, col2 and col3 plus the sum over all col8's for each combination.

Answer (score 1):

By grouping on those columns you are, in essence, making the results distinct on the grouped columns.   So if there were rows that had columns 1, 2, 3, 18, and 19 in common, they would be folded together.

Answer (score 0):

Adding GROUP BY isn't really the correct way to go about this as instead of grouping by the one column it tries to group across the board so you may end up with fewer or greater results depending on the data you're querying.

May I ask for what reason you're grouping the columns?

Comment: I'm trying to group the columns to supply aggregated data to an SSRS report. The report needs column 8 and column 9 but if I include the columns in the select, I need to include them in group by right, since they don't have an aggregate function.